# How to use c structure in python "?

Tags: python, c, wrapper

I have a simple C function.

```
typedef struct {
    long unsigned int First;
    long unsigned int Second;
    int c;
} FRAGMENTS;

struct out {
    long unsigned int Four;
    FRAGMENTS fragments[10000];
};
struct out test() {
    struct out *out = (struct out *)malloc(sizeof(struct out));
    ...
    return *out
}
```

How to use this function in Python ? Any example for transform this structure to python object ( using python wrapper ) ?

Comment: Why are you returning an `int` from the C function? The right return type here is an `out*`.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have the data already "in" Python (i.e. from the network or a binary file)? Than you an use the [struct](http://docs.python.org/library/struct.html) module.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to use [SWIG](http://www.swig.org/) to generate [a Python wrapper](http://www.swig.org/Doc1.3/Python.html) around your C code. You can also use it to generate bindings/wrappers for lots of other scripting languages to.

Comment: For calling the function, and translating input and output to/from Python objects, use SWIG.  Using the memory *structure* directly in Python is not supported because there is no way it could be portable.  (Different CPU architectures and compilers may cause `sizeof(FRAGMENTS)` and the arrangement of its fields to vary.)